# VB.NET AppendText (Out of range)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am attempting to run this code every 5 seconds:

```
    Form2.RichTextBox1.Clear()
    Dim ioFile As New StreamReader("C:\Users\*********\linetest.txt")
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim line As Integer

    While ioFile.Peek <> -1
        lines.Add(ioFile.ReadLine())
    End While

    line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 1)

    Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = (lines(line).Trim())
    ioFile.Close()
    ioFile.Dispose()
```

It runs well, changing the text every 5 seconds. After changing it about 8 times it will crash saying "ArgumentIndexOutOfRange"

Anyone know why? I can't seem to find it on this site.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a new question, use the "Ask Question" button to ask it instead of editing over your old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with where you are generating your random number for line -> line = rnd.next(lines.count() + 1)

If rnd.next generates the actual line.count() value, which is possible since you are adding 1 to the count, then when you pass that value as an index for lines, it will be larger than the highest possible index for the list.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just removed the + 1 and it is working now!

Comment: Now there is another problem. Edited above.

Comment: It sounds like this person gave the correct answer, but you changed the question.  The rules for SO, say that you should accept this answer, and make a new question with your new code.

Comment: It says I can't make a new question that's why I changed it here. Am I going to get banned?